# Flash based network of navigable links

Tags: flash, treeview, networking, flashdevelop

I found this site: http://www.silobreaker.com/FlashNetwork.aspx?DrillDownItems=11_81046 and i'm trying to figure out how such a flash component can be made. I'm sure the data points mentioned are predefined beforehand rather than "live", so thta part's fine, but how are the secondary nodes spread out, how does double clicking on another one, open up another set?

Does anyone have any idea of how this is done? Any exmaples elsewhere on the web that i can have a look at/???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate parts to this. The first is a web service that returns the node data. Here is the [initial data](http://www.silobreaker.com/NetworkService.axd?DrillDownItems=11_81046&types=City%2CCompany%2CProduct%2COrganization%2CKeyphrase%2CPerson&noNodes=30&includeEntities=11_81046&widget=Network&operation=Search). If you look through that JSON data you can see "FromId", "ToId", "Strength, etc.

The next part is the Flash side. All that does is renders the data in it's own way. It looks like it uses the parameters in the data to build relationships between node. It would be pretty tricky to work out exactly how it's working, but that is a good start.